# Salesforce - Admin - Object restriction

Tags: object, access

This question is about Salesforce Object access restriction.
Assume that I have one profile that is assigned to 10 different users. I want to restrict an object access for one user alone without changing the assigned profile or creating a new profile. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove/restrict a user's permissions below their profile level. Instead, you would want to remove the object access for the profile, then create a Permission Set with that object's access granted, and add the remaining nine users to the Permission Set.

Comment: I would go so far as to recommend not granting any permissions in the profile (which is only used for record type and layout assignments) and move all permissions into permission sets. Salesforce is on a journey to deprecate profiles, so doing as suggested helps you be aligned with this future.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to restrict delete permission for that particular user you can create a Record Flow to achieve it. But if your intention is to restrict all the crud operations for that particular user going for a permission set is the best solution as @Sfdcfox mentioned above.